# How to hover image and zoom in and show boxshadow inset

Tags: html, css

Hello I have some image want to display when user hover my image it zoom in and box-shadow inset ,,, please help

Answer (score 1):

```css
img{
  transition: transform 1s;
}
img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey, -2px -2px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
```

Comment: Thank you for answer love u xxxx i try now :)